# rxjs forkJoin emit value only once

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying understand how fork join rxjs operator behavior and I made a little tests.  I've found out that after fork Join emit a the first value its unsubscribe or complete (Not sure) and cannot be produce any values. Is it correct ?
[My code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-forkjoin-example-dxkwbh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)   "rxjs "forkjoin" example"

From the code attached. Only after clicking on both buttons forkJoin can emit the values from observable 1 and observable 2 as expected. But the second time i did this test. Clicking on buttons 1, 2, Nothing happens. This behavior is not documented and I am not sure if I did something wrong. Can someone give me clarification on it ? Thanks

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, forkJoin, from, fromEvent, 
interval, Observable, of, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` 
    RXJS EXAMPLE. See Console

     <button (click)="test1()"> click 1</button> 
    <button (click)="test2()"> click 2</button> 
     <div *ngIf="data">
    {{data}}
 
    </div>
   `,  
})

export class AppComponent  {

   private source1 = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
   obs1$ = this.source1.asObservable();
  private source2 = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
   obs2$ = this.source2.asObservable();

test1(){

 var randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)*2;
 this.source1.next(randomVal);
 this.source1.complete();

}

test2(){  
 var randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
 this.source2.next(randomVal);
 this.source2.complete(); 
 }

 constructor() {
   forkJoin([ this.obs1$,  this.obs2$])
  .subscribe(res => {
   this.data = res; });
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [`forkJoin` documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) you can see:

> That means `forkJoin` will not emit more than once and it will complete after that. If you need to emit combined values not only at the end of lifecycle of passed observables, but also throughout it, try out `combineLatest` or `zip` instead.

This is what happens in your example: after 1 click stream is `competed` and next values ignored.

In order to change this behavior, you could remove `.complete()` call and use:

- `combineLatest` to emit value on any new click
- `zip` to emit when both buttons were clicked

Comment: Thanks, this is what is thought. But if you remove the   .complete() forkjoin will not emit any values, because he is wafting for all other observable to be completed . (well documnet)